# WooCommerce API: Passing email address in the right way

Tags: javascript, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I try to fetch some data from the WooCommerce API with:

```
let currentUserEmail = "test+test@my-url.com"
let apiURL = 'https://www.url.com/wc-api/v3/customers/email/' + currentUserEmail;
```

or

```
let currentUserEmail = "test+test@my-url.com"
let apiURL = 'https://www.url.com/wc-api/v3/customers/email/' + encodeURIComponent(currentUserEmail);
```

In both for this email address case I get a 404 error. I think this is because of the `+` sign. How can I pass the email address correctly to send the get request in the right way?

Comment: + shouldn't be allowed in email addresses but apparently is valid for some reason. The problem is that a + in a URL is an encoded space so you 1. definitely need to encode it 2. the API might not support it

Comment: Thanks, these are my thoughts also. And sure. I can encode it, but the WooCommerce API has to decode it in the backend, right? There I have no chance to manipulate the code..

Answer (score 1):

Email is not it's own endpoint but instead a parameter of customers so you should do this instead

```
let currentUserEmail = "test+test@my-url.com"
let apiURL = 'https://www.url.com/wc-api/v3/customers?email=' + currentUserEmail;
```

You can find documentation of all parameters available here: https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#list-all-customers

Comment: Thanks, but this will not solve the problem with the plus sign on the string. Still user not found :-)